# Why am I getting a 404 on this in react with node

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to send the data inserted into form to server via ajax request like this:

```
 handleUserSubmit: function(user) {
   var users = this.state.data;
   user.id = Date.now();
   var newUsers = users.concat([user]);
   this.setState({data: newUsers});
   $.ajax({
     url: this.props.url,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     data: user,
     success: function(data) {
       this.setState({data: data});
     }.bind(this),
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       this.setState({data: users});
       console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
     }.bind(this)
   });
 },
```

and the rendering is done as:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <UserBox url="../users" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('data')
);
```

I am getting this weird console error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)
```

Since the "users" file (assuming it's trying to access users.json file is in a directory up one level). I have tried all variation possible : "./users", "../users", "#/users" etc...

The code error on this line:

```
url: this.props.url,
```

in the code given above. Any idea what's going on?

My node.js code is:

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(USERDATA, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    var users = JSON.parse(data);
    var newUser = {
      id: Date.now(),
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      address: req.body.address,
      phonenumber: req.body.phonenumber,
      email: req.body.email,
      licensestate: req.body.licensestate,
      licensenum: req.body.licensenum
    };
    console.log(newUser)
    users.push(newUser);
    fs.writeFile(USERDATA, JSON.stringify(users, null, 10),              

function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      res.json(users);
        });
      });
     });
```

Comment: You are getting 404 error because `http://localhost:3000/users` doesn't exist on server (i.e. no file called `users` in the root folder - I assume you use webpack dev-server)

Comment: @Alik I understand, however, it was working a while ago and by root folder do you mean the project folder or the folder from which server is run? My users.json file is in folder from which the server is run.

Comment: Have you tried to set `url="../users.json"`?

Comment: I have, gives me same error!! I have posted this question after exhausting everything I know.. (I dread the error would also be something very silly)

Comment: Show us your node.js code.  You will need a `Post` route handler for `/users` on your node.js server.  Unlike some other web servers, node.js servers do NOT serve any files by default.  So, it doesn't matter where users.json is in your file hierarchy.  You need a route for `/users` in your node.js server for the server to do anything when that request is sent.

Comment: @Alik - This is not about files.  This is about routes on the node.js server.  A route may serve a file (or may not), but if there is no route for `/users`, nothing will happen regardless of where the file is.

Comment: couldnt type here sorry see in the question for node.js code (Post)

Comment: It's working guys, I figured I wasn't sending request and refreshing the state. Thank You guys!!!

Comment: @Alik 's answer was not relevant to OP but it helped me find the source of my issue which was pretty similar. I had to check `webpack.config.dev.js` to find out my files had to be on `output.publicPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the state after updating the server